# How can I get WAN interface bandwidth accurately via SNMP on Fortinet firewall?

Tags: snmp, grafana, fortinet, snmpv3

I am getting a sawtooth style of graph on Grafana when I am tying to monitor the ISP WAN interface of my Fortinet firewall. Can someone please guide me on getting the right graph for the WAN interface bandwidth?
The fortinet shows a much smoother and flatter curve but my graph is a sawtooth, here is my OID,
oid = "1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.187"
where 187 is the interface snmp index.
Please guide me on this.

[image]

This is how it looks on Foritnet dashboard,
[image]

Comment: 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.x counts octets, not bandwidth. Just use the difference to the previous value.

Comment: @Zac67 can you explain a bit more without cliffhanging us? ;)

Comment: @djdomi mean bandwidth in bytes = (ifoctets@t1 - ifoctets@t0) / (t1 - t0)

Comment: @Zac67 How can I get a diff between two values at different time stamps in the same series of datain Grafana? Can it be done via the Transform option?

Comment: I am unable to figure out how to get a delta/diff between two values in a query result? I guess it's via Transform but there is no way to get a t0 and t1 for the same seres of data.

Comment: @Zac67 any thoughts on how to implement your suggestion?

Comment: I'd guess you just set that data source to diff type, but I don't know the first thing about Grafana or I would have posted an answer.

Comment: Im unsure but mrtg had some nice tools to scan the target to fetch all kind of snmp mibs, just try them first?

Comment: @Zac67 your original solution worked to capture interface bandwidth. Thanks! I was able to figure out the diff using "non-negative derivative" in Grafana.

Comment: please share the output of your solution as an answer please